# How to switch 'default' sound device controlled by hardware keys in Xubuntu?

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, xubuntu, indicator-sound

I installed xubuntu-desktop on a 12.04 Ubuntu upgrade after finding Gnome3 lacking. I've mostly been happy, but I've found an odd and frustrating bug. My laptop has two sound 'outputs' - an HDMI-out plug I never use, and the onboard speakers/headphones. For some reason, the hardware keys have been mapped to the HDMI output, even if I set it as 'fallback' in pavucontrol, and notify-osd only displays changes in the HDMI output (though the panel indicator volume control controls onboard sound). I'd ideally like both hardware keys and notify-osd to be looking at the onboard sound, though if I can't get notify-osd it's an acceptable loss. Having to click through a bunch of stuff to change volume is driving me crazy, though.

Googling suggested that it /may/ be a Pulseaudio/ALSA conflict, but the hardware keys seem to change at least indicated volume in pavucontrol for HDMI as expected (I don't have an HDMI cable to test actual sound output)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got a clue somewhere to look in 
*Settings / Settings Editor* (not the normal Settings Manager)

Then, under `xfce4-mixer`, there was the setting `/active-card`
which had the value:

`PlaybackHighDefinitionAudioControllerDigitalStereoHDMIPulseAudioMixer`

I selected 'active-card', and hit the 'Reset Property' button. That turned the setting into:

`PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer`

( These names closely follow the names of the *Output Devices* in `pavucontrol` [see screenshot](http://en.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-05072012-121040pm.php) )

After a reboot, it worked. My volume buttons now affect the volume in the speakers.

(Scrub my earlier, now deleted, hint/comment about Play/Pause not working. They (still) work fine in Rhythmbox - that was/is an unrelated problem with `gmusicbrowser`)

This may or may not work for you! :-)

EDIT: For some reason, my xfce profile got corrupted and I've restarted from scratch by `rm -rf ~/.config`. Now, only a few days later, resetting it didn't work for me either, but setting `/active-card` to `PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer` did.

EDIT: If the above did not work try setting this via terminal and xfconf, e.g.

```
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-mixer -p /active-card -s 'PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! No idea why the system thought HDMI should be my default, but I reset those values, rebooted, and now my media hotkeys are working perfectly, no configuration required.

Comment: Cannot edit or create new string, field always resets to "HDAudioGenericAlsamixer".  Consequently no volume hot keys work at all.

Comment: Had to kill xfce4-volumed process, before changing value, otherwise keeps resetting string field.  Result!

Comment: Thank you very much for this! My volume control keys were not working either but now they are fixed. I would just like to let people know that if your language is set to non-US spelling then you need to add the 'ue' to the end of analogue: PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogueStereoPulseAudioMixer

Comment: From suggested edit: If the above did not work try setting this via terminal and xfconf, e.g.

`xfconf-query -c xfce4-mixer -p /active-card -s 'PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer'`

Comment: The solution via terminal works for `Xubuntu 13.10`, too. Many thanks!

Comment: I killed all instances of `xfce4-volumed`, adjusted the value of the `active-card`, restarted `xfce4-volumed`, and re-added my `audio mixer` panel control. All seemed to take well.

Answer (score 6):

For those who do not have `/active-card`, it is not needed anyway, nor is the `xfce4-mixer`.
The sound is going through PulseAudio and therefore the "default" device is selected by the configuration of PulseAudio, and `xfce4-volumed` will only change the "default" outputs volume.

However you can use PulseAudios configuration tool for this, [`pacmd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pacmd).

```
$ pacmd
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>>
```

1. First list the devices on your machine

   ```
   >>> list-sinks
   ```

   It will print a lot of information about your devices, and as visible they all have an index

   ```
   2 sink(s) available.
     * index: 0
       name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo>
           ...
       index: 1
       name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
           ...
   ```
2. You need to set your preferred device as default. As you can see (the **little star**, i.e. `*`, before index:0) my HDMI was the default and I wanted the Analog output.

   ```
   >>> set-default-sink 1
   ```

You may need to kill `xfce4-volumed` and restart it, to have the desired effect without full system restart:

```
    $pkill volumed
    $xfce4-volumed
```

But basically, **that is it**.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am curious how well it will hold up over time as the default source I chose is a bluetooth speaker. I'll update my comment if it ends up not working through disconnect/connect processes.

Answer (score 1):

This fix will also fix the volume control on the Logitech G930 Wireless gaming headsets. (Not sure about the other buttons though) Launch Settings / Settings Editor (not the normal Settings Manager) or open a command prompt and **type xfce4-settings-editor**

Then, under xfce4-mixer
And replace the active-card setting marked Value: to

> PlaybackLogitechG930HeadsetAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer

I've included an image to make it easier to understand

Also if have problems with the headset volume working here's a link that may help
https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce4-volumed/+bug/901338

Basically do a **killall xfce4-volumed** and try moving the volume on the headset again

[image: headset]

Answer (score 1):

In KDE without editing config files, I was able to fix this by right-clicking the volume icon in the task bar and selecting `Select Master Channel...`.

This brought up a KMix dialog where I selected `Built-in Audio Analog Stereo` instead of `GK110 HDMI Audio`. Immediately after clicking `OK` the volume keys on my keyboard started working.

Answer (score 0):

Peters answer also worked for me. However resetting the /active-card deleted the entry. I just added it again:
name: /active-card
type: string
value: PlaybackBuiltinAudioAnalogStereoPulseAudioMixer

Rebooted and I did get an crash-report from /usr/bin/xfce4-volumed, but the controls work again.

Thanks!