# Volume Hot Keys Not Working in XFCE

Tags: sound, 64-bit, xubuntu, bug-reporting

Just installed vanilla Xubuntu 12.04 LTS & updated on a ThinkPad E325 with Conexant CX20671 sound card.  I notice volume hotkeys work under Xubuntu DE but not under XFCE.  Sound settings are completely missing under XFCE.

Bubble bar invoked by +/- hotkeys, is greyed out; though volume slider that resides in system tray still functions.  Muting/decreasing/increasing volume with hot keys has no effect.

Is there a workaround?  If not what package would I report a bug against?

PS:  I'm running 64-bit.

PPS:  It just goes through the motions under XFCE DE, GUI volume will rise & fall, but actual audio will not change.  (This is due to hotkeys being mapped wrong; see below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it may be same issue? 
[How to switch 'default' sound device controlled by hardware keys in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130927/how-to-switch-default-sound-device-controlled-by-hardware-keys-in-xubuntu)

You should check, that 'active-card' in xfce4-mixer settings is proper.

Comment: The volume hot keys were indeed mapped to HDMI.  Followed above guide then Sound Settings ==> Configuration to toggle HDMI off.

Answer (score 2):

As detailed on [this community documentation wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems), press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run this command:

```
ubuntu-bug audio
```

Answer (score 0):

et in to Alsa Mixer 
and check out your audio controls and look em over, same times its gets idle and you have to tutch the mixer and , this usualy works for me (xfce Arch kernel 3.6.9rc7 amd64) and (Xubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.5.x amd64) (Gentoo 3.6.0 xfce TI64 )