# Keyboard Media Volume Control not working

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys

im having a bit of an issue with my volume keys.

They worked fine, until I recently updated (kernel, etc) and installing Ati latest driver. 
The update was a standard update:

```
apt-get update, apt-get upgrade
```

And the Ati Catalyst drivers installed where:

```
amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64
```

I made both installs, a reboot after each one.. but didnt tried volume keys.. so i dont really know which one made the Media keys stop working.

BTW, im running Ubuntu 12.04 with standard Unity interface.

A bit of info:

```
lsusb
    Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
```

The keyboard has 2 sets of media keys, Volume Up, Volume Down, Mute. And aside, Next Track, Play/Pause, Next Track. 
The second set works ok, i can pause, skip, etc...

But the volume and mute keys are not responding. 
The output of "`sudo showkeys`" lists the not working keys as Key 115, 114 and 113.

The configuration on System > Keyboard > Shortcuts is configured fine apparently..

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?
Please let me know if i can get you guys any more info..

BTW, manual control works fine, i mean with the volume applet i can control volume.

Comment: possible duplicated [How to switch 'default' sound device controlled by hardware keys in Xubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/130927)

Comment: It's a bug, see here................ https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1248368

Answer (score 4):

Probably the media keys are not controlling the correct device. Open sound preferences and try to enable/disable things. In my case it helped.

Also see:
[How to switch 'default' sound device controlled by hardware keys in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130927/how-to-switch-default-sound-device-controlled-by-hardware-keys-in-xubuntu)