# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - HDMI sending video, not audio

Tags: sound, 20.04, laptop, hp, hdmi

I have an HP 14 Notebook PC with Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 processor to which I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Issue I'm having is it suddenly stopped sending audio to an external TV when connecting it via HDMI. I do the usual Settings > Sound > Output Device > HDMI / DisplayPort - Built-in Audio, but when running any audio or even using the Test option, no audio comes out from it.

I have tried solutions proposed on [No sound on HDMI Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256043/no-sound-on-hdmi-ubuntu-20-04-lts) with no luck.

Running

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/
reboot
```

OR

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -rf ~/.pulse*
```

I have tried several tested HDMI cables, ports on TV tested with a PS3 and they all work fine.

For the PC reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch again, and searching if the BIOS had any HDMI or audio config options, none which has helped me.

This is the output when running `sudo lspci -v && lsmod | grep snd`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at b2710000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series USB xHCI HC
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at b2700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at b2718000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at b2714000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: 9fb00000-9fcfffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 000000009fd00000-000000009fefffff [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b1000000-b1ffffff [size=16M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000b0ffffff [size=16M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b2600000-b26fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b2400000-00000000b24fffff [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=09, subordinate=09, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b2500000-b25fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at b271c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at 6088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 6094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 6080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 6090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 6060 [size=32]
    Memory at b271b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at b2719000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 6040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at b1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at b2600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at b2400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-36-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    DeviceName: Skyray
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at b2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-23-b7-fe-ff-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be

snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  8
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

I'd really appreciate any help you could give me as I'm relatively new to this Ubuntu world and I am totally out of ideas!